# Dynamically change field value in web2py sqlform

Tags: python, web2py

I want to generate a sqlform.grid using a database table defined as:

```
db.define_table('ClientInfo',
            Field('HostID', type='text', label='HostID'),
            Field('MACAddress', type='text',  label='MACAddress'),
            Field('MachineName', type='text', label='MachineName'),
            Field('IPAddress', type='text',  label='IPAddress'),
            Field('TimeOffset', label='TimeOffset'),
            Field('RunningAs', type='text',  label='RunningAs'),
            Field('SystemVersion', type='text',  label='SystemVersion'),
            Field('OSType', type='integer', label='OSType'),
            Field('AgentVersion', type='text', label='AgentVersion'),
            Field('FirstCheckin', type='datetime',  label='FirstCheckin'),
            Field('LastCheckIn', type='datetime', label='LastCheckIn')
           )
```

The OSType field is an enumerator-type integer and as such I'd like to change it prior to display so that it identifies the OS type not by the integer but by a string (e.g. 0 = Windows XP, 1 = Windows 2012, and what not). Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To change the display in the grid as well as read-only forms, use the `represent` attribute of the field (see the end of [this section](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Field-constructor) of the documentation).

You can also add an `IS_IN_SET` validator, which by default will result in a select widget in any forms (e.g., the grid create and edit forms). You can pass a dictionary or list of tuples to the validator to specify a set of labels to associate with the values (see the end of [this section](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Range--set-and-equality-validators) of the documentation):

```
OS_TYPES = {
    0: 'Windows XP',
    1: 'Windows 2012',
    ...
}

db.define_table('ClientInfo',
    ...
    Field('OSType', type='integer',
          requires=IS_IN_SET(OS_TYPES), # Results in select widget in forms.
          represent=lambda v, r: OS_TYPES[v]), # Sets display value in grid.
    ...)
```

Comment: thanks for the info, but I'm more looking for how to modify the .grid or .smartgrid output so instead of showing 0, 1, 2, etc for the OSType column, it shows the label. I tried modifying the Field() entry as you suggested and it didnt change the .grid output :(

Comment: @tjac Use alternate representation for this. Write a function that return value(e.g. Windows XP, Windows 2012..) for given id/integer (e.g. 0,1..). Read [Field constructor- represent](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Field-constructor).  `db.ClientInfo.OSType.represent = lambda os_id, row: _get_os_name(os_id)`. You can also use dictionary for `IS_IN_SET()` that will be easy

Comment: Sorry, the original answer just focused on forms (which the grid also generates for creating/editing records). The answer has been updated to handle both form widgets and display of values in the grid.